# Azure Application Gateway health check returns 301

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I'm trying to configured an Azure Application Gateway in front of a web app. The web app is empty for now, only a single page to verify its running. I've added a custom domain and dns settings, verified in the network settings of the webapp. I've setup the AG following a few different links as I couldn't get a working example from a single source. I'm at the point now where my health checks are returning a 301. The lister is using port 80 as I have not setup the ssl yet. The app custom domain has no ssl binding either. The network security group has the default settings. I've checked the webapp before adding the private ip and it was fine, its just an empty page. So i'm wondering what could be causing the 301. Anyone have an idea what could be causing that or some further links I can check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved. The webApp had Https Only turned on in the settings, that was the cause of the 301. Doh!